# How do I prevent the option key from performing alternative input when I use it as part of a keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

Usually, the keyboard shortcut will work but I will also get an accent or symbol character in the file editor.

Sometimes, even the keyboard shortcut doesn't seem to work.

I'm new to macos, so maybe this is an os-wide setting somewhere.  However, there are some times when I might need a symbol or accent so I'm perplexed why the option key was chosen as a shortcut key modifier for vscode if its default behavior in a mac is to produce alternative input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option key alone (and with SHIFT) is generally reserved for use by the active keyboard configuration, and is not often used for application shortcuts.  You generally want to have at least COMMAND or CONTROL as part of your shortcut.

Comment: Yeah ok...that confirms my suspicions and I guess vscode just didn't follow this convention.  Guess we just have to redefine the commands that by default use only OPTION or SHIFT+OPTION.